# MVC5 Custom Binding: List of Strings to List of Complex Type

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, model-binding

In the ASP.Net MVC 5 application I'm currently writing, one `Material` can have many names (`MaterialName`s). I have build a web interface to add, edit, and delete those names for the material on the `Edit` and `Create` pages of the material. To achieve this I have multiple `text`-`input`s on those pages which are named `Material.MaterialNames`. Those can be added and deleted client-side with javascript to change the number of names. I do not need indices in the `name`s of the `input`s because the data the user should see and edit is just a flat list of strings.

These are the relevant parts of my models:

```
public class MaterialVM
{
    public Material Material { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class Material
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MaterialName> MaterialNames { get; set; }
    // ...
}
public class MaterialName
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int MaterialId { get; set; }
}
```

Now all would work great if `Material.MaterialNames` would be of type `List<string>`. In my case the model binder can not create `MaterialName`s from the multiple string values passed as form data. I believe the default approach to fix this would be

**Writing a custom model binder**

Is it a good idea to do that like [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15501381/1200847) (= Override `BindProperty` and just change the behaviour for one PropertyType)? I would combine that with [globally registering the binder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746472/using-modelbinder-attribute-vs-modelbinders-add) for the type `MaterialVM`.

**Do I miss a simpler option?**

Isn't it possible to just offer the default binder a method to cast/convert/serialize/... a simple type to a complex type? Is my approach how to write a custom model binder correct? Are there any other options I'm missing which would make this more intuitive?

Comment: Refer the answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161481/post-a-form-array-without-successful/29161796#29161796) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28019793/submit-same-partial-view-called-multiple-times-data-to-controller/28081308#28081308) for dynamically adding and deleting complex objects from collections

Comment: I know about the possibility of using indices. I was looking for a solution without them, because I think they produce much html-overhead without any need for that, given that I have only one string per index.

Comment: Since you editing a collection of complex objects, you must use indexers (there is no way to match up which `Name` belongs with which `Id` and `MaterialId` property otherwise, especially if you dynamically adding and deleting items even if you were to create a custom ModelBinder`). You can only avoid the indexers if your property is `public List<string> MaterialNames { get; set; }

Comment: In theory I do not need more information than I have. I would have to add the index just for the binder. My idea was to implement i.e. an [overridden cast](http://stackoverflow.com/a/725517/1200847) to enable the binder to convert strings to `MaterialName`s. That leads to the question: are the non-complex types the binder supports hard-coded? Does the binder use any kind of standard deserialization method so that I could add the conversion logic at that point?

Comment: It would not make sense to do any of that. Assume you have existing items M1, M2 and M3 and in the view you delete M2 and add M4 and change the name of M3 to M5. There is no way that you could then identify which items you need to add, update of delete in the database unless you have the associated `ID` property and the only way that can be done is by providing indexers.

Comment: In general that's true. But in my special case it's much simpler. I do not care if the user changed one element or deleted and recreated it. I'm just interested in which strings the user wants to exist, not at which position,... . I just use the id for working with the database, not for anything else. When the user clicks save I simply compare (`string.Equals` is perfectly enough) the names the user sent to the names in the db and then change the db accordingly.

Comment: That would be awful from a performance point of view, but if you really wanted to do that, then just make your model property `List<string>` instead of `List<MaterialName>`. But again, if a user changed the value of one item, and you only compare the string values, you would have no idea if that item was a new item or an existing item (because nothing would exist in the database with that name.

Comment: That's true but isn't a problem. For me there isn't a difference between `update` and `delete + insert`. Given that my n and m will not ever grow over ~15, the list compare complexity of `n*m` doesn't seem to be worth thinking about.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a complex type using the default model binder, but you need to add a `.Index` property to your repeating control's template.

Here is the simplest example I could think of for your case:

```
@model WebApplication25.Models.MaterialVM

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Material.Id)
    <table id="output">
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>MaterialId</th>
            <th>Id</th>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <button id="add-more" type="button">Add Another</button>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
}
@section scripts{
    <script>
        (function (window) {
            "use strict";
            var index = 0;
            $("#add-more").on("click", function () {
                $("#output").append(
                  "<tr><td>" +
                  "<input type='hidden' name='Material.MaterialNames.Index' value='" + index + "' />" + // add in the index
                  "<input type='text' name='Material.MaterialNames[" + index + "].Name' /></td>" +
                  "<td><input type='number' name='Material.MaterialNames[" + index + "].MaterialId' /></td>" +
                  "<td><input type='number' name='Material.MaterialNames[" + index + "].Id' />" +
                  "</td></tr>");
                index++;
            });

        }(window));
    </script>
}
```

This example should result in them appearing in your view model:
[image: Model bound data list]

Comment: I did something similar to your solution just to make asp.net MVC model binding to work with the list of complex objects, since the posted values must have the index value in sequential order. In the end, I've dynamically added those hidden input fields before the form got posted.

Comment: @KMC The indexes actually don't have to be sequential. For example, in that code above, we could do `index += 2` to deliberately skip values - it will still bind. They do all need to be both positive and unique values, though.

Comment: I remember having random indexes like account.name[0] and account.name[10]. I'll give it another try. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The view model should be catering to the view so it should probably have a

`List<string> materialNames`

The MVC binding will bind to the view model.

Then in the controller or whatever layer you handle the mapping you can map the *MaterialVM* to *Material*.

Comment: I do not really like the idea because I need to duplicate data and structure/objects, just to fit the binder's needs. Additionally I need to add extra logic at all places where I want to present or let the user change those names. Possibly it's the best option though :/

Comment: I agree with you and that is why I am not a big fan of MVC(as a framework) or any framework that dictates how you build an application. I usually build services, or use websockets on the server side and plain html and javascript or typescript on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

If you cache your `MaterialVM` in a session variable or `Id` and `MaterialNames` in a `Dictionary<int, List<string>>`, then you can post back to the action the `id` and a `List<string>` of the names. Using the `id`, you can look up the material, then update the model.

Alternatively, in JS, you can `JSON.stringify` your form data, then parse it on the server side.