# JSON Deserializing modified class. Custom JSON Deserialize method

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I had a class that I was regularly serializing and deserializing.
One of its fields used to be a string to represent a road, but has since been changed to its own class.

```
class Foo
{
    public string RoadRef;
}
```

Has now been changed to:

```
class Foo
{
    public Road RoadRef;
}

class Road
{
    public Road(string val)
    {
        Lane = val[0];
        Number = int.Parse(val.Substring(1));
    }

    public char Lane;
    public int Number = 1;
}
```

Now I'm getting errors when I try to deserialize from strings that were serialized with the old version of the class. I have a lot of old serialized files that I don't want to go back and reserialize to the new format, especially since changes like this will likely happen again.

I should be able to specify a custom method to Deserialize (and Serialize) for `JsonConvert.Deserialize` right?
Is there a better approach to deal with this problem?

The closest I've got so far is adding a `[JsonConstructor]` attribute above the constructor as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23017716/json-net-how-to-deserialize-without-using-the-default-constructor), but it didn't help the deserializing crashes.

The original JSON looks like this: {"RoadRef":"L1"}
It throws this exception:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: 'Error converting value
>   "L1" to type 'Road'. Path 'RoadRef', line 1, position 15.'
>
> ArgumentException: Could not cast or convert from System.String to Vis_Manager.Road.

Comment: What does your Json look like?

Comment: I think you might need a [custom JsonConverter<T>](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm) to do this.

Comment: @AndrewE have added the JSON and exception now

Comment: looks like it might be because it doesnt know that L & 1 are two different objects.

Comment: @AndrewE it doesn't, but it knows that it's supposed to be a Road object. I was thinking there might be some way "L1" be redirected to create a Road object through the constructor Road(string) ?

Comment: have you try casting it?

Comment: What do you mean by casting it? I think the only thing I can call when deserializing is the actual deserialize method, I can't cast any data types or execute any user code while it's running because it's all internal.

Comment: Can't you just deserialise to an older version of the class when required?

Comment: @DavidG an ugly hack but would work. I will include that in my code for the meantime but don't want to confusingly keep to versions of the same class as a long term solution.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with multiple versions of the class if you have multiple versions of your data.

Comment: @DavidG unfortunately it's not feasible in this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stuartd suggest, you could use a custom JsonConverter to explicitly say how to convert a string to your data type.

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{""RoadRef"":""L1""}";
    var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json);
}

public class RoadConverter : JsonConverter<Road>
{

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, Road value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override Road ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Road existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.ValueType != typeof(string))
            return (Road)serializer.Deserialize(reader, objectType);

        var data = reader.Value as string;
        return new Road(data);
    }
}


public class Foo
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(RoadConverter))]
    public Road RoadRef { get; set; }
}

public class Road
{
    public Road(string val)
    {
        Lane = val[0];
        Number = int.Parse(val.Substring(1));
    }

    public char Lane { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; } = 1;
}
```

If you don't want to use Attribute decorator and keep your model out of any serialization concern, you can use it as parameter of DeserialzeObject method

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json, new RoadConverter());
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a custom `JsonConverter` you could use the [`implicit`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit) operator to convert directly from a string:

```
public class Road
{
    public Road(string val)
    {
        Lane = val[0];
        Number = int.Parse(val.Substring(1));
    }

    public char Lane { get; set; }
    public int Number { get; set; } = 1;

    public static implicit operator Road(string val)
    {
        return new Road(val);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to add an [overriding cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725435/overriding-cast) from string to the class.
The JSON Deserialize method tries to explicitly cast the string value to the class, which is now possible.

```
public Road(string val)
{
    Lane = val[0];
    Number = int.Parse(val.Substring(1));
 }

public static explicit operator Road(string val)
{
    return new Road(val);
}
```